# Close App, App should not be in background

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new with this, we have an app with ionic and cordova and client wants to close the app and remove it from background, is there a way to do this? I already research but I could not find anything. Any help? Thanks
We are closing the app with this

```
 ionic.Platform.exitApp();
```

Comment: Your client doesn't seem to understand how the Android platform works. You'd think people have figured it out in the past 6 years, but apparently they haven't. (by default you're meant to close all activities and then the Android system decides when to terminate your application)

Comment: Thanks @EpicPandaForce